# Facebook SendDialog on Mobile Website

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a mobile app which provides a login via facebook. I tried to avoid loading the facebook jdk on my mobile website because it is way too big for mobile, I think. So I do most of the login on [server side](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). On the client

My login works like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}6response_type=token&
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

The response I get is an access token which I can use to get user data from facebook.

Now I want to do a [message send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/). This simples solution is this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123050457758183
  &link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html
  &redirect_uri=https://www.bancsabadell.com/cs/Satellite/SabAtl/
```

The only problem is that the user has to login to facebook in his mobile browser after he has been logged in to my app. I think this is no good practice to require the use to make two logins.

**Is there a way to use the access token to make the send request?** 
**Can I send a message to another user using the Graph Api?**

Note that I still have a valid access token from the user since I got an access token after he has give me permissions on login to my mobile website.